# why does this assertion between two strings fail?

Tags: python, python-3.x, assertion

I'm taking a class with Stepic. I have what I think is a simple assertion between two strings that fails. How else can I check for equality? Thanks, Jim

```
def weights_to_letters(peptide):
    '''
    take a list of weights and convert to a string of aa letters
    '''
    from Bio.Data.IUPACData import protein_weights
    ret_string = ''
    for weight in peptide:
        for key in protein_weights.keys():
            if weight == round(protein_weights[key] - 18):   # -18 for weight of extra water molecule
                ret_string += str(key)
                break
    return ret_string
def test_weights_to_letters():
    print(type('WDG') , 'WDG', type(weights_to_letters([186,128,113])),     weights_to_letters([186,115,57]))
    assert weights_to_letters([186,128,113]) == 'WDG'
```

This is what comes out:

```
<class 'str'> WDG <class 'str'> WDG
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jim\My Documents\GitHub\Stepic-Rosalind\BioAlgWeek2.py", line 238, in <module>
testcode()
  File "C:\Users\Jim\My Documents\GitHub\Stepic-Rosalind\BioAlgWeek2.py", line 228, in testcode
   test_weights_to_letters()
 File "C:\Users\Jim\My Documents\GitHub\Stepic-Rosalind\BioAlgWeek2.py", line 209, in    test_weights_to_letters
assert weights_to_letters([186,128,113]) == 'WDG'
AssertionError
```

Comment: You're printing the value of this: `weights_to_letters([186,115,57])`, but in the comparison, you're using this: `weights_to_letters([186,128,113])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have a typo in the first line of test_weights_to_letters(). You're passing [186,115,57] to weights_to_letters, but you're asserting weights_to_letters([186,128,113]).

Comment: That's embarrassing:)

Comment: @JimSmith But easily fixed, which is so much nicer!